# Can SQLAlchemy cache updates

Tags: sqlalchemy

I would like to use SQLalchemy to update rows in a potentially large table using the ORM interface. But im not clear about something.

My question is, assuming I have one session doing repeated selects and some updates, are these updates happening in the database or are they sometimes buffered in some ORM cache object?

For example, If I'm repeating a select with a session which yields 10 rows like this:

```
session.query('User').filter(User.val == 42, User.surname == 'Dent')
```

.. but I only update the last row of that 10,

1. Will the ORM always fetch the same 10 rows from DB or will it use cached values?
2. will any caching behavior change with transaction markers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear what you mean by "use cached values for updates", but I'll try to outline the behavior in general:

```
query = session.query(User).filter(...)
```

**This does not do anything with the database.** This constructs a `Query` object that represents your query.

```
users = query.all()
# or
for user in query:
    ...
```

This will always execute a `SELECT` query to fetch the rows from the database, *converts them into in-memory objects*, and puts them into the identity map. (This is maybe what you mean by a cache.)

```
user = users[0]
user.surname = "Bar"
```

This records the fact that you want to update the `surname` column to `"Bar"`, but it doesn't actually do anything to the database.

```
session.flush()
```

This issues `UPDATE` queries to the database.

```
session.commit()
```

This *flushes if there's any pending changes*, issues a `COMMIT` query, and (by default) **expires all instances in the identity map** so that doing `user.surname` at this point issues a `SELECT` query (but just for that row, i.e. `SELECT ... WHERE id = ...`).